# Error in named configuration

Tags: domain-name-system, centos6

i'm currently studying DNS and have run in to the following errors in my centos6 VM. this is the tut i'm following [tutorial](https://www.ostechnix.com/setup-dns-server-step-by-step-in-centos-6-3-rhel-6-3-scientific-linux-6-3-3/)

```
  [root@server1 named]# sudo service named start
Starting named:
Error in named configuration:
zone example.tv/IN: has no NS records
zone example.tv/IN: not loaded due to errors.
_default/example.tv/IN: bad zone
rev.example.tv:1: unknown RR type '1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.'
zone 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: loading from master file rev.example.tv failed: unknown class/type
zone 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: not loaded due to errors.
_default/1.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: unknown class/type
zone localhost.localdomain/IN: loaded serial 0
zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 0
zone 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
zone 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
                                                           [FAILED]
[root@server1 named]#
```

here is my fwd.example.tv file:

```
$ORIGIN example.tv.
$TTL 86400
@       IN SOA server1.example.tv. root.example.tv. (
        2018021011;serial
3600; refresh
1800;retry
604800; expire
86400;min TTL
)
@IN     NS      server1.example.tv.
@IN     NS      server2.example.tv.
server1         IN      A       192.168.1.17
server2         IN      A       192.168.1.20

~
~
```

here is my rev.example.tv file:

```
@ORIGIN 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.
$TTL 86400
@       IN      SOA     server1.example.tv.     root.example.tv.(
2018021011; serial
3600; refresh
1800;retry
604800; expire
86400; minimum TTL
)



@IN NS server1.example.tv.
@IN NS server2.example.tv.
server1 A 192.168.1.17
server2 A 192.168.1.20
17 IN PTR server1.example.tv.
20 IN PTR server2.example.tv.
~
~
```

here is my /etc/named.conf file:

```
Code: Select all
options {
       listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 192.168.1.17; };
        listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        allow-query     { localhost; 192.168.1.0/24; };
        allow-transfer {localhost; 192.168.1.20; };
        recursion yes;

        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;
        dnssec-lookaside auto;
        /* Path to ISC DLV key */
        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};
zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
};




zone "example.tv" IN{
        type master;

file "fwd.example.tv";
allow-update {none;};
};

zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN{
type master;
file "rev.example.tv";
allow-update{none;};
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `named-checkconf` and `named-checkzone` to check your configuration and zonefiles.

Spoiler alert: `@IN` is not valid syntax, it must read `@ IN`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my problem lies in the way the zone files should be constructed which worked for me so i'm posting my working solution for others who face the same problem in the future. I actually missed to add example.tv. NS in the right way in fwd.example.tv file and rev.example.tv file so here are my working soln's.

the right way to keep the zones is as follows:

```
$ORIGIN example.tv.
$TTL 86400
@       IN SOA server1.example.tv. root.example.tv. (
2018021000
3600
1800
604800
86400
)

@               IN      NS      server1.example.tv.
@               IN      NS      server2.example.tv.

server1         IN      A       192.168.1.17
server2         IN      A       192.168.1.20
example.tv.     IN      A       192.168.1.17
~
~
```

the right way to keep the reverse zone is as follows:

```
$ORIGIN 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.
$TTL 86400
@       IN      SOA     server1.example.tv.     root.example.tv.(
2018021011; serial
3600; refresh
1800;retry
604800; expire
86400; minimum TTL
)



@       IN NS server1.example.tv.
@       IN NS server2.example.tv.
server1 A 192.168.1.17
server2 A 192.168.1.20
17 IN PTR server1.example.tv.
20 IN PTR server2.example.tv.
        IN      NS      example.tv.
1       IN      PTR     example.tv.
~
```